# Angular Service not getting injected in component - Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to inject a service `SpotifyService` into a component `SearchComponent`, the service takes `Http` as parameter.

here's my module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, RouterModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, SearchComponent, ArtistComponent, AlbumComponent, TrackComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [{
    provide:SpotifyService,
    deps: [Http], useFactory(http:Http){
        return new SpotifyService(http);
    }}]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { from, Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, catchError, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class SpotifyService {

  constructor(public http: Http) { }

  searchTrack(query:string){
    let params:string = [
      `q=${query}`,
      `type=track`
    ].join("&");

    let queryUrl:string = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?${params}`;

    return this.http.request(queryUrl).
pipe(map((e)=> e.json()),
      catchError((e:Response)=> throwError(e)));
  }

}
```

Search component definition:

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  query:string;
  results: Object;
  constructor(private spotify: SpotifyService,
  private router: Router,
  private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params=>{
      this.query = params["query"] || "";
    });
  }
}//etc...
```

however at runtime I am getting blank screen with the error `Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)`

Here's stackblitz fiddle: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-spotify-ngbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  providers: [{
    provide:SpotifyService,
    deps: [Http], useFactory(http:Http){
        return new SpotifyService(http);
    }}]
```

Why are you declaring it with a factory?
Just provide it like `providers: [SpotifyService]` and DI inject all dependencies for you.
And for that, you also should import `HttpModule` and `RouterModule` correctly

```
imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, RouterModule.forRoot([]), HttpModule ]
```

And set some valid routes.